# Inno Setup and MS Access .accde database

Tags: inno-setup

I hope someone can help. I have a small MS access database which I've converted into a .accde file and have managed to get Inno Setup to create a setup file which generally works.

When I install it on a Windows 7 machine and double click on the desktop shortcut that was installed it just works. However, if I install it on a Windows 8 machine and double click the desktop shortcut it works but it can't attach to the backend database. When I set the desktop shortcut advanced properties to run as administrator, it then works perfectly.

Just two quesitons if someone who know either Access or Inno or both.

1. Is it possible to get Inno to create a shortcut with the Run as Administrator set?
2. Is there soething with Access runtime that I'm not seeing or getting correct.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Old entry but maybe still worth a try:

- the directory is readonly when you create it so writing is forbidden (should be the same for Win 7 but maybe you changed the security settings and Inno setup used the existing folder)
- try the following: add the app directory with special permissions:

> [Dirs]
>
> Name: "{app}"; Permissions: everyone-full

If that works change the settings to something more secure like "AuthenticatedUsers-Full" or something similar

you should NOT need to run access with admin rights! But just to answer your question:
[How to set 'Run as administrator' on a file using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978917/how-to-set-run-as-administrator-on-a-file-using-innosetup)

Comment: Yes, you should not need to run Access with admin rights because you should save that database into the application data folder which is used for this purpose. So, avoid storing that database into the program files folder would be a better advice.