# Visual Studio Setup Project: Failed to execute script after installing app and opening it

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

So I finished an app, made an .exe, and the original .exe works, but when I try to install the app, the .exe and shortcuts to the .exe don't work. I get this error message: [Failed to execute script (app name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf7g0.png)

Is there a solution to this or should I make the installer another way or on another computer? In the meantime, I'll try to look into other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I switched to Inno Setup and the first time I built the installer it worked. But after building again, the same error occurred. I eventually tried running the app as admin and it worked, so to fix the issue, I added something in the registry to make the app run as admin by default. [This is how you do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978917/how-to-set-run-as-administrator-on-a-file-using-inno-setup)

Comment: or you could just simple right click on the exe file select the compatibility tab and check the run as admin file and then package the application, you wouldn't need to go through the registry inputs.